# How to calculate an unknown variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages, word-problem

We had this fictional business in class with the following information.

The business achieved sales that were $3$ times higher than total purchases.

Trading expenses were $25 \%$ of total purchases.

The business had $4,000$ in the bank and this was half the amount it had incurred in operating expenses.

Premises were acquired for $75,000$ and $33 \%$ of this was funded by a bank loan.

Inventory was the equivalent of $2$ months sales revenue.

The question is to find the capital of the business, but there are too many unknown variables. Can anyone figure out how to handle this assignment?

Comment: Maybe represent it in a form of system of equations?

Comment: Could it be the *capital* is just the 50,000 worth of premises (after deducting bank loan) plus 4,000 in the bank?